# How do you insert a text file into a Linked List in an orderly fashion? Java

Tags: java, text, linked-list, java.util.scanner

I have a text file as follows:

```
head    World
tail    westerly
head    duck
head    doorstop
position    3   kickplate
tail    Nested
head    Kite
tail    easterly
head    cavello
head    weatherstripping
position    6   sheathing
head    street
tail    screen
head    ducting
head    thermopane
position    6   collaborate
head    mouse
tail    vane
head    tale
tail    tail
head    window
head    caulking
position    5   termostat
head    green
tail    northernly
head    platipus
head    stoop
position    12  team
head    asia
tail    africa
head    america
head    europe
position    15  roundRobin
```

And I need to be able to insert this text file into a LinkedList. Although, I cannot insert the word "head" into the list I have to insert the second word into the list at head, tail, or position "whatever position". How do I do this? For example I have to insert World at head(the first line) and then Westerly at tail(the second line). It has to be done in a way that I can also take "position 3 kickplate" and put kickplate at position 3 since the format is different for different items.

This is my code so far, all I have done is made a LinkedList TarepList and put all of the text file words into it but they are not in any order.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

public class TarepList {

public static void main(String [] args) {

    List<String> TarepOne = new java.util.LinkedList<String>();

    try{
        File file = new File("AddData.txt");
        Scanner calladd; 
        calladd = new Scanner(file);

    while(calladd.hasNext()){
        String item = calladd.next();
        TarepOne.add(item);
    }

    for(int i = 0;i < TarepOne.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(TarepOne.get(i));
    }


    calladd.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("file not found");
    } // catch




    // Open the AddData.txt file and add the items appropriately to the list


    // Print out the entire list


    // Open the RemoveData.txt file and remove the specified items from the     list


    // Print out the entire list


    // Empty the TarepOne list and then print out the entire list

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some parsing. This would happen in the `while` loop. Something like this:

```
while (calladd.hasNext()) {
    String command = calladd.next();
    if (command.equals("head") {
        String item = calladd.next();
        // put item at the beginning
    } else if (command.equals("tail") {
        String item = calladd.next();
        // put item at the end
    } else if (command.equals("position")) {
        int pos = calladd.nextInt();
        String item = calladd.next();
        // put item at position pos
    }
}
```